# What are some ways to implement developer specific optins in JAVA?

Tags: java, configuration

Our team inherited a big project in a language we aren't great at.  We're pretty good about creating feature branches, but as things grow in complexity we would like to have developer specific options to turn on or off certain features.  We are all C# / .NET shop so we're not up to speed on the best way to do this in JAVA.

I see Application Context, POM.XML and other files, but can someone show me a simple way to do something like...

```
if (DeveloperConfig.useDevWidget1) {
   // do dev / non ready for release stuff
} else {
   // do old code we're trying to replace
}
```

I'm sure this is easy but looking for best practices where each developer could turn on or off their options in their branch and then we turn things on or delete the old code after is passes QA checks.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read about [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in `pom.xml`

Comment: It depends on your type of project (desktop app with a main? Web app? Java we start app? Etc.). You could put an option in the pom but it's probably messy. You could pass an argument to your main method, if there is one. Or you could use a system property.